# GUI on 4k Monitor too small

Tags: 4k-monitor

I built a home theatre PC with ubuntu and got a 4k monitor for it. But the GUI is too small to read. In the settings, there is an option to scale to 200% but I think this scaling is also for videos. But of course I do not want to scale videos, I only want to scale the GUI.
Can I scale the GUI and keeping the possibility to view 4k videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaling setting has nothing to do with multimedia playback.